# Looping through and comparing lines of two unequal length dictionaries

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 files of unequal length that each contain a column of names. I would like to use fuzzywuzzy to compare these names and identify matches. However using the script below instead of comparing all the  values in the name column in file1 to all the values in the name column in file2 it only compares the first line of file1 to all the lines of file2. Can someone please help with a script to do all pairwise comparisons? Thanks!

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from  fuzzywuzzy import process
import csv

file1_loc = 'file1.csv'
file2_loc = 'file2.csv'

file1 = csv.DictReader(open(file1_loc, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
file2 = csv.DictReader(open(file2_loc, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for line in file1:
    for line2 in files2: 
        partial_ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(str(line['NAME']), str(line2['PNODENAME'])) 
        if partial_ratio > 60:
            bus_name.append(line['NAME'])
            pnode_name.append(line2['PNODENAME'])
            score_50_plus.append(partial_ratio)
            print partial_ratio 
            print line['NAME']
            print line2['PNODENAME']
```

*Edit* To clarify I have a list of 218 names I'll call list1 and a list of 1172 names I'll call list2. I think that the names in list1 correspond to some of the names in list2 but they aren't exact matches so I can't do something roughly like:

```
matches = []
    for line in list1:
        if line in list2:
            matches.append(line)
```

Instead I'd like to get the fuzz.partial_ratio of each name in list1 to each name in list2 . Something like :

```
for line in list1:
    partial_ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(line, list2[0]
for line in list1:
    partial_ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(line, list2[1]
for line in list1:
    partial_ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(line, list[2])
```

Without having to write 1172 for loops ( or 218 if I reversed it).

Comment: It is due to 2 nested for loops, so that's why your program in running n^2 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue was that the iterator for `files2` was consumed by the first iteration through `files1`. Recreating the iterator for each iteration of `files1` fixed the issue.

Since you want to do a line-by-line comparison, nesting the loops will not help - the two iterators have to "move together". We can use `izip` from `itertools` for this purpose:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
for l1, l2 in izip_longest(file1, file2):
    if all((l1, l2)):
        partial_ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(str(l1['NAME']), str(l2['PNODENAME']))
```

You would replace the 2 `for` loops you have with the `izip` construct above.

Comment: Thank you, I actually tried this before posting. The problem I ran into was that the files are of unequal length izip joins on the shortest file so it doesn't go through both lists fully. I also tried izip_longest (the same as map(None, file1, file2)) which joins on the longest file but it then just adds the "Nones" to the shorter file. Then after doing some it produces the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Comment: Why not use `izip_longest` and check for `None` in either of the 2 items? You can also use the `fillvalue` argument to pass a different default (empty string?).

Comment: Okay I just tried that. Now it stops at the same spot but gives the error: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str.

Comment: I have updated my code - `all` will only run the `fuzz.partial_ratio` iff both `l1` and `l2` are non-None.

Comment: I think adding all actually just recreates using izip instead of izip_longest because it only compares the columns when both are non -null, essentially joining on the shortest column. I have a list of  218 names(l1) and a list of 1172 names(l2). I think that the names in l1 correspond to to names in l2 but not exactly so I can't use "in". Instead I'm trying to use fuzz.partial_ratio to find which they're most like.

Comment: In that case you can't get away from the nested `for` loop approach.

Comment: I know but I don't know how to do it :( because the nested for loop only looks at the first line of the second for loop

Comment: The issue is that the iterator for files2 has been consumed. Move the DictReader call for files2 immediately after the first for loop.

Comment: Yes!! I'm pretty sure that's working! Thank you so much!